# Temporary holding collection of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Which is the best method to temporary hold and access collection of data between one more controllers?

For example, `view1.cshtml` contain a grid with the following data items:

```
--------------------
Name | Address | Age
--------------------
aa   | ad1     | 11
--------------------
bb   | ad2     | 22
-------------------
cc   | ad3     | 33
--------------------
```

and if a user selected first 2 rows, then the selected row items needs to be displayed in a grid on another another view named `view2.cshtml`. The user can go back to first view again and if select a new row item , then I want to to append the selected item too to the grid displayed on the second view.

I've tried ViewBag and TempData to temporarily store the data. But unfortunately the data getting cleared on sometimes. Which is the best option to solve this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Since the information on your grid came from some data source, most likely a database which has a unique identifier, when the user clicks on the rows I would simply redirect the user to the other page and pass along the ids of the selected rows.

On the other controller, you would simply retrieve the data for the ids that were passed in.

Comment: I think this is the better option as with MVC you should always consider a stateless approach first.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pass your object in the action like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { data= items });
```

The controller action method signature could be something like:

```
public ActionResult LoginFailed(List<T> items)
{
    ...
}
```

Another way is to store it in tempdata like this, and its once readable, after once read, it si automatically destroyed:

```
List<AnyType> items = new List<AnyType>();


TempData["MyList"] = items;
```

And in other controller action read it like this:

```
List<AnyType> items = (List<AnyType>)TempData["MyList"];
```

if you want it to be accessable after reading call this:

```
TempData.Keep("MyList");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use Session to store the collection of data since you need to pass data between one or more controllers.

Save:

```
List<T> items = new List<T>();
items.Add(T);
...

Session["YourCollection"] = items;
```

Get:

```
List<T> items = Session["YourCollection"] as List<T>;
```

Comment: Don't go stuffing data into session just for the sake of holding on to it for another post or two. That is the quintessential bad design.